# ANR only when using "setVisibility"

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar, freeze, android-anr-dialog

this is my first android app, and I have the following problem with [this](http://pastebin.com/ar5MZGac) code:

```
package com.example.andbro;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        String myURL;
        WebView browser;
        ProgressBar progressBar;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                this.myURL = "http://www.google.com/";
                this.browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                this.progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

                Button rel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {

                                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                                progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);

                                if (newProgress == 100) {
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                } else {
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }

                        }
                });

                browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                browser.loadUrl(myURL);

                rel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                browser.reload();
                        }
                });

        }
}
```

It is a simple **Webview** that loads a webpage ( Google ), with a reload **Button** and a **ProgressBar**.

So while the page is loading, I check if the progress in *onProgressChanged* is 100 or lower than 100: if it is 100, I hide the progress with:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

else

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Hovewer my app freeze and then it ends showing me an ANR message. Just commenting those two lines, and everything works ( obviously the progress bar won't hide in that case ).

It doesn't crash if i put, for example, two Toasts like "start" or "end" after the if/else statement.

Why is this happening only with *setVisibility*?

Also [this](http://pastebin.com/Bw2H1m1f) is the logcat log for both status( with or without those lines )

```
11-20 12:01:13.979: W/ApplicationPackageManager(29061): getCSCPackageItemText()
11-20 12:01:13.979: I/PersonaManager(29061): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
11-20 12:01:14.019: V/WebViewChromium(29061): Binding Chromium to the background looper Looper (main, tid 1) {429e2bf8}
11-20 12:01:14.019: I/chromium(29061): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
11-20 12:01:14.019: I/BrowserProcessMain(29061): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
11-20 12:01:14.029: W/chromium(29061): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
11-20 12:01:14.039: W/ApplicationPackageManager(29061): getCSCPackageItemText()
11-20 12:01:14.039: I/Adreno-EGL(29061): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
11-20 12:01:14.039: I/Adreno-EGL(29061): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08+13
11-20 12:01:14.039: I/Adreno-EGL(29061): Build Date: 03/28/14 Fri
11-20 12:01:14.039: I/Adreno-EGL(29061): Local Branch: 0328_AU200_patches
11-20 12:01:14.039: I/Adreno-EGL(29061): Remote Branch: 
11-20 12:01:14.039: I/Adreno-EGL(29061): Local Patches: 
11-20 12:01:14.039: I/Adreno-EGL(29061): Reconstruct Branch: 
11-20 12:01:14.109: D/ProgressBar(29061): setProgressDrawable drawableHeight = 0
11-20 12:01:14.209: D/OpenGLRenderer(29061): Enabling debug mode 0
11-20 12:01:14.219: D/ProgressBar(29061): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
11-20 12:01:14.219: D/ProgressBar(29061): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
11-20 12:01:14.219: D/ProgressBar(29061): updateDrawableBounds: right = 1080
11-20 12:01:14.219: D/ProgressBar(29061): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 30
11-20 12:01:14.219: D/ProgressBar(29061): updateDrawableBounds: mProgressDrawable.setBounds()
11-20 12:01:14.229: W/AwContents(29061): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-20 12:01:14.279: W/AwContents(29061): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
11-20 12:01:14.339: I/chromium(29061): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
11-20 12:01:14.379: I/chromium(29061): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
```

Comment: are you sure that it is ANR? but anyway first remove else at all ... and put set visible inside button click(and before loadUrl if it is not visible in the layout) so it whould be run only once ...

Comment: @Selvin nope, it keeps freezing. After a very long time it shows me the ANR message ( this -> http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy4qv.png )